Alternative to --install-option in newer python versions
When using python 3.8 I installed PyMQI with the following command:
pip install pymqi --install-option server

In order to make pip install run as if I had instead issued this command:
python setup.py build server

I see that in python 3.12 (and perhaps earlier?) the --install-option flag has been removed.
What pip command can I now use to achieve the same?
Attempting to replace --install-option with --config-settings results in the following error:
Arguments to --config-settings must be of the form KEY=VAL


It says here to use --config-settings

Yeah - I saw that too, but when I replace --install-option with --config-settings it says the arguments must be of the form KEY=VAL. So what, EXACTLY, do I supply as the value?

Stab in the dark... try --config-settings="--build-option=server" ?

Thanks @sytech - tried it - but it doesn't install the server version so I don't think that's it.

So you tried: pip install pymqi --config-settings="--build-option=server" ?

Yes @BendingRodriguez that is what I tried.
